# When are the different jQuery Ajax error codes returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

In the jQuery-docs they state that there are 4 possible error codes:

- `parserror`
- `timeout`
- `abort`
- `error`

I've noticed that `parserror` is given when the the reponse content-type is `application/json` but jQuery failed to parse it

and `timeout` when the server doesn't respond within 30 seconds.

This is helpful because based on these codes I can display some useful error message in the browser.

The problem is that I'm not sure when these two other codes are returned and from what I read on Google it seems that `abort` should be returned when the network connection is down but when I tested this I got `error` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's ajax error handlers have three arguments returned

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {...
```

- The first is the XHR object, containing the request
- The second is the error, as a string, which is the one you're refering to
- [The third is the actual network error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072267/what-would-an-ajax-errorthrown-response-be/40072430#40072430), if one is returned, such as `404 Not Found` etc

For the second argument, there are five possible return values

- null
- timeout
- error
- abort
- parsererror

`null` is retured when the error can't be specified by one of the other options

`timeout` is returned if the request times out. The duration before a timeout occurs can be set with the `timeout` option

`error` is returned if a network error occured, and the third argument will also be populated with the code, as in `.fail(function(jqXHR, "error", "Not Found" )`

`abort` is returned if the request is aborted. An XMLHttpRequest can be aborted by using the [`abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) method

`parsererror` is returned if $.ajax is given a `dataType` option, or if the response has a content type set, that makes jQuery try to parse the response as HTML, JSON, XML etc. and the response can't be parsed as such, and the parser fails.
When this happens, the request is successful, it's only the response that can't be parsed.